# Certain Image Augmentation Prevent Unet Model from Learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, loss-function, image-segmentation, data-augmentation

I am training a Unet model for cell image segmentation from microscopy images. In order to help the model generalize better to different microscopes, I attempted to apply brightness augmentation to the training data, randomly multiplying images by a value chosen between (0.5, 1.5), then normalizing each image.

However, adding this augmentation always caused the model to get stuck at a very high loss (using jaccard loss). Interestingly, in the absence of this augmentation, the model converged to a jaccard score of 0.50. A similar effect was observed when applying random Gaussian blurrin: the model failed to learn. On the contrary, spatial augmentations such as flipping, rotating, etc did not have this effect.

I performed extensive testing on my code verified that the image augmentation function worked correctly and that the cells were still recognizable from blurred/darkened/brightened images.

I thought that the model cannot escape some local minima in the loss landscape. So, I experimented with a variety of weight initialization including HeNormal and HeUniform. I also tried first training first without augmentation and then using the weights to train with the brightness and blurring augmentations. Nothing worked. I am using Relu activation function and Adam optimizer. I tried to switch to SGD to see if it would help, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Random levels of brightness could make the results worse because brightness is often related to sharpness as far as I know.

A low brightness would generally have a low sharpness, and vice-versa. If you have a high brightness with a low sharpness, this would make more confusion during the learning process, and this would alter generalization.

Consequently, if you improve the sharpness, you would improve the results.

Therefore, you can [measure it](https://github.com/xinario/defocus_segmentation) to confirm that images with a good sharpness are better than the other ones.

Then, you can use simple solutions like [OpenCV](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/08/sharpening-an-image-using-opencv-library-in-python/) to improve it, but if you have enough quality data, you can use [VAE/GANs](https://github.com/harsha070/Sharpness-improvement-in-VAE-and-VAE-GANs) to improve sharpness greatly.